# OnActivityResult Not call when use android:noHistory

Tags: android

A value of android:noHistory **true** means that the user will not be able to return to it.

So OnActivityResult method not call. i want to use that method to get uri from phone storage. so it is compulsory to use OnActivityResult method or any other idea how to do that?.

Comment: If the User not able to return to that page, how "OnActivityResult" will be called.

It will be called only if the stack history is available.  check this url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39715619/onactivityresult-not-called-when-pressed-back-arrow-on-screen-but-only-called-wh/39718652#39718652

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to android documents  when you use **android:noHistory true** means not possible call ActivityResult() .

A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it. 
            In this case, **onActivityResult() is never called** if you start another activity for a result from this activity.

Refer [Details](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)